# for Java language, how to add the next string to the list

Tags: java, arraylist

What I want to do is to turn the words in file "star.txt" to an array of list. When I compile these code, it tells me hasNext is an illegal statement. I'm wondering how to fix it?

```
public static ArrayList<String> fun(File file) throws Exception { 
    ArrayList<String>  result = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("star.txt"));
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        result = s.addNext();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `hasNext()`.  `addNext()` however, isn't a method on `Scanner`, so I will believe that you get an error there.

Comment: check out the docs for `Scanner.next`.....

Comment: If there's a problem with the filename will `s` be a scanner? If it fails would `s.hasNext()` be an error because the resulting value of `s` is not a `Scanner` object with that method?

Comment: @ToothlessRebel What? If you construct a `Scanner` object it *will* be a `Scanner`. It can't be instantiated as some other type just because it "fails".

Comment: @Jashaszun Was a new to Java question. In untyped languages it may be null or undefined or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with `hasNext` method. Compiler complains about lack of `addNext` method. You should use `next()` instead.
Also this method returns next word from file, so you need to store it in list. To do this use

```
while (s.hasNext()) {
    result.add(s.next());
}
```

Since Java 8 you can also use `s.forEachRemaining(result::add);` instead of this loop.